# Django template not getting view data

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Im trying to make my own app called Services, I have been following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/) on how to make your own app.

I am making this app in Django CMS, I essentially want this app to contain templates that I can then insert into pages of the CMS via the `includes` tag.

I have made my models, views, urls and template. But the template isn't receiving any data from the view. I am able to create new service objects in the backend so I know my model is working how I want and I'm not getting a template error when including it.

Here are my models, views, URL file and template. I suspect it is either something to do with how I setup my view or how I'm pulling my view in the URLs file.

Currently the only output I get in the template is "No Services Available" which it is set to output when there is no service_list from the view.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField
import filer.fields.image
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
from colorfield.fields import ColorField


class Service(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
  slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=50, populate_from='title')
  color = ColorField(default='#FFFFFF')
  tab_content = HTMLField(blank=True,help_text='Describe the service you offer and how that might benfit people.')
  page_content = HTMLField(blank=True,help_text='Describe the service you offer and how that might benfit people.')
  quote = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
  icon = filer.fields.image.FilerImageField(verbose_name='Image',blank=False,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='+',)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import View, ListView, DetailView, TemplateView

from .models import Service


#Create your views here.
def tabs(request):
  services_list = Service.objects.all()[:5]
  context = {'services_list': services_list,}
  return render(request,'service_tabs.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.tabs, name='Service Tabs'),
]
```

template

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% if services_list %}
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <div id="services" class="container">
    <ul id="services_list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

       {% for service in services_list %}
         <p>{{ service.title }}</p>
       {% endfor %}

    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- End of: Nav tabs -->
{% else %}
 <p>No Services Available</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: do you have data in the database in the service table

Comment: I do, and that is also being pulled through to the CMS admin menu.

Comment: remove the comma from this line and check context = {'services_list': services_list,}

Comment: I removed the comma and then added {{ context }} to my template. After a server restart nothing is still outputted.

Comment: no you need to do {{ services_list }} in the template,

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: inside your view function after this line services_list = Service.objects.all()[:5] add print(services_list) and check in the terminal if anything is printed or not when you go to the url of this view

Comment: I inserted that into the view and I didn't see an output on any page that im calling the template. I then replaced it with a string and didn't see the string either, im guessing then that my view isn't getting applied from the urls file

Comment: check in the cmd where you are running the command python manage.py runserver

Comment: AH I did, sorry I didn't make that clear, I meant I didn't see the list in the terminal when I visited the pages that use the template.

Comment: change this line from .models import Service to from . models import Service, give a space after .

Comment: That didn't seem to have worked either

Comment: idk if this matters for this specific case but your name in your url cannot contain spaces. you should use lowercase underscores. If your print statements in your view tabs view isn't being printed, then the view isn't being hit. maybe the name fix that I mentioned above will fix it.

Comment: If you run `python manage.py shell`, `from YOURAPP.models import Service`, then `Service.objects.all()` you should see all the Services stored on your database, right?

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron I ran those commands and I get an array output of all of my services, there is definitely nothing wrong with my models.

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick I don't have spaces in my URL, I use hyphens when a URL has multiple words in it. I do agree though that the view isn't being hit though for some reason, if you can think of any reasons why that might be I would love to hear them.

Comment: @samroberts707 Weird then, your code is well, use ipdb (pip install ipdb) after context declaration `context = {'services_list': services_list,} import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` and check the data

Comment: your url name has spaces though. `url(r'^$', views.tabs, name='Service Tabs'),`

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick this was just me playing around making the name more verbose, I was having the problem with just `tabs` and again when I change it to `services_tabs`

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron Im not able to see any output from the view currently, I am printing and logging the context to try and see it in my terminal window.

Comment: @samroberts707 And What do you have in the context?

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron I'm not able to see the context as I'm not getting anything logged or printed from that view. Whether that is a variable such as context or even if I try and just print `Hello World`, I see neither.

Comment: Q1: Do you have the template you've modified as one of the templates available to select on the page in Django CMS? If not, you need to add the template to the ```CMS_TEMPLATES``` object in your settings.

Comment: Q2: Are you sure you've selected the correct template for the page in Django CMS? If you can't see "No Services Available" or your services, it sounds like this could be the problem?

Comment: @tdsymonds As stated in the question I want to use this template inside another template, this will just be a small tabbed section on a longer page, for testing though I have added it to the Django CMS and created a stand alone page with just this template but I still get the same No Services Available.